# Issue with Sharepoint Modal Dialog in Chrome

Tags: sharepoint, google-chrome, modal-dialog

**Scenario:**
I have a solution on a webpage, and I have a SharePoint web part. The solution is showed as an Iframe.In the web part I have a SP Modal dialog. When I try to pop up this modal dialog through the web part, It goes behind the solution iframe. This happens only on Chrome[and most probably safari], for the other major browsers IE 8/9, FF, it works fine.

**So Far:**
I tried to adjust the Z indexes but this has not helped.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.